# Correlation between variables over time

Tags: time-series

I have two variables over two different years. Week by week pageview numbers in 2013 and 2014 and week by week # of posts in 2013 and 2014 (number of articles posted).

I'm trying to find out if posting less frequently has caused a dip in pageviews.

Right now I am taking the percentage difference for pageviews and posts and looking for correlation between the week over week percentage differences.

Can anyone help with me a more accurate analysis?